# Return Sub String that comes before a 10 digit contact number from a String

Tags: php, string

Hi I am not able to write a PHP code which return all sub strings(which come just before 10 digit number).

The Input String is  "8826835575 jagadish jagadish82017@gmail.com varanasi 221311 yes na yes 1 na 9560153352 jaggu jagdish@vedittechnologies.com delhi 123456 yes na yes 1 na 9555176779 jpkeshari jpjagadish@yahoo.com noida 221311 yes na yes 1 na"

**desired output :**

substring 1 = "8826835575 jagadish jagadish82017@gmail.com varanasi 221311 yes na yes 1 na "
substring 2 = "9560153352 jaggu jagdish@vedittechnologies.com delhi 123456 yes na yes 1 na "
substring 3 = "9555176779 jpkeshari jpjagadish@yahoo.com noida 221311 yes na yes 1 na"

Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP function `preg_split` with option `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` returns an array alternating 10 digit number, string, etc.

```
$subject = '8826835575 jagadish jagadish82017@gmail.com varanasi 221311 yes na yes 1 na 9560153352 jaggu jagdish@vedittechnologies.com delhi 123456 yes na yes 1 na 9555176779 jpkeshari jpjagadish@yahoo.com noida 221311 yes na yes 1 na';
$result = preg_split( '/(\d{10})/', $subject ,'-1' , PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
array_shift($result);
for ( $ii = 0; $ii < count($result); $ii++ ) {
  print $result[$ii] . $result[++$ii] . '<br>';
}
```

First element is empty so `shift` that off, then loop through array printing pairs. These can be saved to another array or variables instead of printing here.

Outputs:

```
8826835575 jagadish jagadish82017@gmail.com varanasi 221311 yes na yes 1 na 
9560153352 jaggu jagdish@vedittechnologies.com delhi 123456 yes na yes 1 na 
9555176779 jpkeshari jpjagadish@yahoo.com noida 221311 yes na yes 1 na
```

Comment: i require output..Like this...array[0]=> 8826835575 jagadish jagadish82017@gmail.com varanasi 221311 yes na yes 1 na [1] => 9560153352 jaggu jagdish@vedittechnologies.com delhi 123456 yes na yes 1 na

Comment: thank you...:) this is the code which I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

`preg_split()` is nice but cryptic. Here's an alternative solution:

```php
<?php
$input = "8826835575 jagadish jagadish82017@gmail.com varanasi 221311 yes na yes 1 na 9560153352 jaggu jagdish@vedittechnologies.com delhi 123456 yes na yes 1 na 9555176779 jpkeshari jpjagadish@yahoo.com noida 221311 yes na yes 1 na";

// 1. Replaces all 10 digits preceded by an space by an carriage return.
$output = preg_replace('#\s(\d{10})#', "\n$1", $input);

// 2. Stores the string by line by line in an array.
$output = explode("\n", $output);

// array (
//   0 => '8826835575 jagadish jagadish82017@gmail.com varanasi 221311 yes na yes 1 na',
//   1 => '9560153352 jaggu jagdish@vedittechnologies.com delhi 123456 yes na yes 1 na',
//   2 => '9555176779 jpkeshari jpjagadish@yahoo.com noida 221311 yes na yes 1 na',
// )
var_export($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve the issue easily using the PHP function split by regular expression, [preg-split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with pattern `/[0-9]{10}/`:

### Solution

```
<?php

 $subject =  "8826835575 jagadish jagadish82017@gmail.com varanasi 221311 yes na yes 1 na 9560153352 jaggu jagdish@vedittechnologies.com delhi 123456 yes na yes 1 na 9555176779 jpkeshari jpjagadish@yahoo.com noida 221311 yes na yes 1 na";

 $pattern = '/([0-9]{10})/';
 $val = preg_split ( $pattern , $subject, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

 for ($i=0; $i < count($val); $i+=2){
    print($val[$i].$val[$i+1]);
 }

?>
```

### Explanation

You split first the monolithic string by means of `preg_split`, taking as separator any combination of numbers of 10 digits. Note that we are using here the option `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` with `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` to capture also the number, as for your requirement.

Then you have an array organized as follows:

```
[0] => first delimiter // your number
[1] => what follows
[2] => second delimiter // your second number
[3] => what follows
...
```

You just have to merge the resulting array the way you prefer (I did with a dumb for cycle, you can find a better PHP-nic way to do it). The result will be the following, as you wanted:

```
8826835575 jagadish jagadish82017@gmail.com varanasi 221311 yes na yes 1 na
9560153352 jaggu jagdish@vedittechnologies.com delhi 123456 yes na yes 1 na
9555176779 jpkeshari jpjagadish@yahoo.com noida 221311 yes na yes 1 na
```

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: Yes, I am modifying the answer with a better explanation.

Comment: thank you for your quick response...But i require 10 digit contact number in the starting of each sub string........like
8826835575 jagadish jagadish82017@gmail.com varanasi 221311 yes na yes 1 na

Comment: updated to return your expected output and with a description about the (not so) cryptic preg_split, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

if you want exactly this output, you can use something like this:

```
$input = "8826835575 jagadish jagadish82017@gmail.com varanasi 221311 yes na yes 1 na 9560153352 jaggu jagdish@vedittechnologies.com delhi 123456 yes na yes 1 na 9555176779 jpkeshari jpjagadish@yahoo.com noida 221311 yes na yes 1 na";

$splited = preg_split('~(\d{10})~', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$lines = array_map(function($item) use ($input) {
    return substr($input, $item[1] - 10, 10) . $item[0];
}, $splited);
var_dump($lines);
```

if you want to create an associative array, whichs probably an better output, this would help:

```
$input = "8826835575 jagadish jagadish82017@gmail.com varanasi 221311 yes na yes 1 na 9560153352 jaggu jagdish@vedittechnologies.com delhi 123456 yes na yes 1 na 9555176779 jpkeshari jpjagadish@yahoo.com noida 221311 yes na yes 1 na";

$splited = preg_split('~(\d{10})~', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$i = 0;
$lines = array_reduce($splited, function($carry, $item) use (&$i) {
    ++$i % 2 ? array_push($carry, $item) : $carry[array_pop($carry)] = $item;
    return $carry;
}, array());
var_dump($lines);
```